# Django logging output that doesn't seem to be part of root

Tags: django, python-logging

I'm trying to understand Django's logging output so I've separated out all the core django loggers (django, django.request, django.db.backend, core, django.template) and set their levels to WARNING and gave it it's own formatter to make it more easily distinguishable from the rest.
I've also overridden the root logger, set it to debug and made a similar easy to notice formatter for it.
So now I get stuff like this:

```
127.0.0.1:99999 - - [08/Nov/2023:00:50:06] "GET /static/frontend/main.js" 304 -
ROOT CRAP ! >>>>>>> [2023-11-07 16:50:10] - daphne.http_protocol - HTTP response complete for ['127.0.0.1', 99999]
127.0.0.1:99999 - - [08/Nov/2023:00:50:10] "GET /api/auth/user" 200 606
ROOT CRAP ! >>>>>>> [2023-11-07 16:50:12] - daphne.http_protocol - HTTP 200 response started for ['127.0.0.1', 99999]
ROOT CRAP ! >>>>>>> [2023-11-07 16:50:12] - daphne.http_protocol - HTTP close for ['127.0.0.1', 99999]
ROOT CRAP ! >>>>>>> [2023-11-07 16:50:12] - daphne.http_protocol - HTTP response complete for ['127.0.0.1', 99999]
127.0.0.1:99999 - - [08/Nov/2023:00:50:12] "POST /sg/query/user_tasks" 200 6001
```

But I still don't know where those REST logs are originating from (ie the ones that don't say ROOT CRAP!). I assumed they'd be a part of the root log stream but apparently they aren't? Is there another Django-level logger that I've not accounted for. These are likely coming from my front end but I'm not clear how Django is consuming those logs.

Thanks in advance for any clarification you can send my way!

-Mark

[EDIT - here's the config]

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'root': {
            '()': TZOffsetFormatter,
            'format': 'ROOT CRAP ! >>>>>>> [%(asctime)s] - %(name)s - %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            'timezone': "US/Pacific",   
        },        
        'simple': {
            '()': TZOffsetFormatter,
            'format': 'DJANGO LEVEL STUFF? [%(asctime)s] - %(name)s - %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            'timezone': "US/Pacific",   
        },
        'okta': {
            '()': TZOffsetFormatter,
            'format': 'OKTA!!! %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)-s - %(funcName)s: %(lineno)d - %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            'timezone': "US/Pacific",            
        },
        'sg': {
            '()': TZOffsetFormatter,
            'format': 'SG!!! %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)-s - %(funcName)s: %(lineno)d - %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            'timezone': "US/Pacific",            
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'root_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'root',
        },
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'okta_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'okta'
        },
        'sg_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'sg'
        }        
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['root_handler'],
        'level': 'DEBUG'
    },
    'loggers': {}
}

django_loggers = {
    logger_name: {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': True,
    } for logger_name in [
        'django',
        'django.request',
        'django.db.backends',
        'django.template',
        'core'
    ]}

LOGGING['loggers'].update(django_loggers)
```

Comment: You might want to add another logger for all undefined python modules. For this just add `''` which is an empty string to your list of logger names in your `django_loggers` dict

Comment: I tried doing this and it did print out a lot of extra stuff but that front end (i assume) traffic logging never seems to be involved. I printed out all the other loggers in my project and tried overriding a few with a different handler but it seems to be out of my control.

Comment: Are you running django development server or do you have something else sitting in front of it like gunicorn or nginx

Comment: daphne but this is currently out of my development server. my prod server is through an aws load balancer/ec2 instance. I'm able to capture the daphne logs which is why i figured this must be something different.

Comment: i see. that probably explains it. It could be your load balancer because the logging pattern resembles Common Log Format (CLF) which is associated with Apache or Nginx. It has got its own logging config and wont use your django logging configuration. You will also notice that the service responsible for that logging is running on port 99999

Comment: Except that these logs are coming out of my local development server. It *is* also happening in my aws application. The reason I'm bringing this up is that I'm sending a whole lot of these logs to Sumo logic and I'd prefer to keep this "noise" out of the logs. However if I can't determine what it is I'm not sure how to keep it out, per se. Unless of course I can write a custom handler that only allows in the logs I want based on their logger name or...something.